# Retrofit with dynamic URL

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

in my application am using a Retrofit 2.9.0, my issue is the user can change completely the URL from the app menu, in this case is not working when i changed the URL only if i restart the app.

this my instance of Retrofit :

```
object ApiService {

var token: String = ""

@JvmName("setToken1")
fun setToken(tk: String) {
    token = tk
}

private val globalInterceptor = GlobalErrorInterceptor()
private val loginInterceptor = LoginErrorInterceptor()

private val okHttpClient =
    OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(globalInterceptor).build()

private val okHttpClientLogin =
    OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(loginInterceptor).build()

var gson = GsonBuilder()
    .setLenient()
    .create()

 /**This instance for the  others requests */
private val retrofit by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(LOGIN_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()

}

val API: WebServicesApi by lazy {
    retrofit.create(WebServicesApi::class.java)

}

/**This instance for the login to get the Token */
private val retrofitLogin by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(LOGIN_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClientLogin)
        .build()

}

val APILogin: WebServicesApi by lazy {

    retrofitLogin.create(WebServicesApi::class.java)

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change retrofit URL by doing something like this. First change `retrofit` from `val` to `var`.

```
private fun changeBaseUrl(url: String) {
    // change the base url only if new url is different than old url
    if (retrofit.baseUrl().toString() != url) {
        retrofit = retrofit.newBuilder().baseUrl(url).build()
    }
}
```

Please note you might have to change this method and call it according to your flow. The main point to note here is the use of `.newBuilder().baseUrl(url).build()`.